# Which way should this capacitor go on this circuit?

Tags: capacitor, ac, synchronous-motor

Which way should this capacitor go on this AC Hysteresis Synchronous motor circuit? Which terminal is CCW and which is CW?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that capacitor polarized or non-polarized? If it's non-polarized, then the capacitor orientation doesn't matter

Comment: CW = clockwise, CCW = counter-clockwise, in case you weren't aware. So the labels on the switch simply need to be made to fit whichever way the rotor turns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capacitor is not polarized. Either way works fine.

Comment: Agreed...the CW and CCW refer to the switch positions rather than the capacitor.